# Sending an email through java

Tags: java, collections, oracle11g

As I want to send email using java ,all data for an email which I am storing in table. 
One table is header table where I am storing email subject,body,and email_id
im second table I am storing email to,email_cc,email_bcc fields and foreign key which is primary in header table,as one mail configuration has multiple email_to,email_cc,email_bcc fields

so basically which collection class I will be use.

Comment: what have u tried so far

Comment: Basically am sending an alert to customers.so my procedure is checking data in table if customer has low balance this is one type,

Comment: And another am giving one screen for client for sending an email as he wants.as am using scheduler which checks open item in header table if he gets then will send email

Comment: post your code so that solution can be specific

Comment: Am not started yet,but can you give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As you got no replies yet (it's been 15 hours since you asked the question), here's a *workaround* as I don't speak Java, but I know how to send mail from an Oracle database. So, if you're interested in it, have a look.

User which is supposed to send mails should be granted EXECUTE privilege on `UTL_MAIL` (and/or `UTL_SMTP`; check those packages in Oracle documentation).

```
SQL> -- connect as privileged user (SYS, if there's no other)
Connected.
SQL> grant execute on utl_mail to scott;
```

Then, connected as SCOTT (i.e. user which sends mails), create a simple procedure which looks like this:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_mail (par_recipient   in varchar2,
  2                                      par_subject     in varchar2,
  3                                      par_message     in varchar2)
  4  is
  5  begin
  6     utl_mail.send (sender       => 'me.myself@gmail.com',
  7                    recipients   => par_recipient,
  8                    mime_type    => 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
  9                    subject      => par_subject,
 10                    message      => par_message);
 11  end;
 12  /

Procedure created.

SQL> begin
  2    p_mail('someone@gmail.com', 'Test', 'Message text goes here');
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Basically, that's it. You can make the procedure as rich as you want it - pass parameters to it, or create local variables which would contain subject and/or message text, loop through multiple recipients, use CC, ...

Based on your description, it would be a relatively simple task to make it work.

Saying that your *procedure is checking data in table and sends mail if a customer has low balance*: I'd suggest you to create a database **JOB** (search for `DBMS_JOB` and/or `DBMS_SCHEDULER`) and it'll do it all for you.

However, if you must do it in Java, sorry - I barely know how to say "Hello, world!" (with some help of my dear friend, Google).